# Validating uniqueness of a record in a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, join

I have a join table with this setup:

```
create_table "showable_videos", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "profile_id"
  t.integer  "video_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

How do I validate the uniqueness of a `showable_video`? In other words, I need to make sure no two `showable_videos` have all the same `user_id`, `profile_id`, and `video_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having a model ShowableVideo and put there:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:profile_id, :video_id]
```

Comment: any reason why there is a space between `:` and `profile_id`?